# Python Syntax doubt

Tags: python

Hey, I have been using the Pymt library and they have this convention to referring their widgets:

```
from pymt import *

# create a slider from 0.-1.
sl = MTXYSlider()

@sl.event
def on_value_change(x, y):
    print 'Slider value change', x, y

runTouchApp(sl)
```

what's with the "@"? What does it signify in Python?Thanks.

Comment: How sad that the Python tutorials weren't working.  Which tutorial have you been using?  How long has it been down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It signifies a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

Answer (score 0):

basically it is a function that takes another function as an argument . if is a way python implements a [Decorator Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

the equivalent code would be

```
sl.event(on_value_change(x, y))
```